# Google search shows "No information is available for this page." in description

Tags: robots.txt

In Google, there is no description for my site. I found a robots.txt file in my /var/www directory and deleted it a few weeks ago, but when I search for my site on Google, it still shows the same thing: "No information is available for this page."

I have done a "locate robots.txt" and found some but not in any folder that is visible on the web. I deleted them anyway.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out. Even though I could not find any robots.txt files on my server, I did find that on my Wordpress sites that don't have a description in the search field, the checkbox under Settings->Reading, "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" was checked.

I checked the setting out on all the sites I host and it seems the ones with that box checked are the ones showing up with the message "No information is available for this page." and the ones that did not have that box checked are fine. I am not sure how Google knew not to crawl the site, because I deleted the robots.txt files I found, etc. but it must have a way to track it other than that file.

I fixed the setting and am crossing my fingers the search results start to display a description for the site.